# If function: turn into whole number when decimal is .0

Tags: after-effects, animation, after-effects-expressions

I've created this slider and counter which works just fine going from `5x` down to the `W`:

[image: current view]

The problem is that I need to create a condition that when a number hits `.0` it becomes a whole number, so in this case below, it shouldn't be `5.0x` but `5x`:

[image: problem]

Here is my current expression:

> `effect("Slider Control")("Slider").value.toFixed(1) + "x";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screengrab]

Here's the code:

```
myval = effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
SourceText = (Math.round(myval * 10))/10 + "x"
```

It's a really non-intuitive thing, but multiplying the value by 10, then rounding it to the nearest whole number, then dividing by 10 gives you what you need.

Think of it as "how many values after the decimal point do I want?" and count the number of zeroes in the number used.

Comment: That is not intuitive at all! Thanks for explaining it to me :)